# BATCH- How to put a variable into the move command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Okay, this is my first question on Stackoverflow, so I'll try to make it a good one.
I've searched all over the web and I couldn't find any information to this. I have created a little batch file that prompts you to put in the name of a file that you would like to move. After that, it asks your your usersname. The problem I'm having is cmd tells me I have incorrect syntax.

Can anyone see what I did wrong?
Below is the code I am using. I just pasted in the part that is having trouble.

Thanks guys!

```
echo Place the file you wish to move to the Windows Startup Folder on your desktop.
echo When you have placed it there, type in the name of your file, NOT INCLUDING the extension.
echo Example: The file's name is: myfile.bat You type in: myfile
set/p "filename=>"
echo %filename%
echo Next, type in your username.
echo Example: acly6
set/p "USERNAME=>"
echo %USERNAME%
ping 192.2.0.0 -n 1 -w 500 > nul
goto MOVE
:MOVE
echo Moving your file to your startup folder.
move C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%filename%.bat 
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
ping 192.2.0.0 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul
echo Checking Volumes...
ping 192.2.0.0 -n 1 -w 3000 > nul
if EXIST C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Startup\%filename%goto COMPLETED
goto FAILED
```

Comment: `%username%` is a systemvariable. So you don't need to ask the user for his name. Also `%appdata%` could make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

I editted a bit your script: 
  Surrounded filepaths with double quotes
  Added /y parameter to move command to override automatically the file in new location (if exists)
   Spotted some issues:
goto MOVE 
:MOVE has no sense as it will continue anyway that path.
goto FAILED   GOTO COMPLETED - there're no such labels in your script.
Please shout if you have other problems.

```
@echo off
echo Place the file you wish to move to the Windows Startup Folder on your desktop. 
echo When you have placed it there, type in the name of your file, NOT INCLUDING the extension. 
echo Example: The file's name is: myfile.bat You type in: myfile 
set/p "filename=>" 
echo %filename% echo Next, type in your username. 
echo Example: acly6 
set/p "USERNAME=>" 
echo %USERNAME% 
ping 192.2.0.0 -n 1 -w 500 > nul 
goto MOVE 

:MOVE 
echo Moving your file to your startup folder. 
move /Y "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\%filename%.bat" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
ping 192.2.0.0 -n 1 -w 1000 > nul 
echo Checking Volumes... 
ping 192.2.0.0 -n 1 -w 3000 > nul 
if EXIST "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\%filename%" goto COMPLETED 

goto FAILED
:FAILED
```

Comment: It will be a local variable in the instance of CMD. Though - maybe it is better to be avoided.